# Clientes que estén de cumpleaños el siguiente mes

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Me pidieron en una tarea de la uni mostrar los clientes que estén de cumpleaños el siguiente mes a la ejecución. Este código llevo, solo me falta saber como hacer que me muestre los del siguiente mes.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NUMRUN,'99G999G9999') "RUN CLIENTE"
     , PNOMBRE ||' '|| SNOMBRE ||' '|| APPATERNO ||' '|| APMATERNO "NOMBRE CLIENTE"
     , TO_CHAR(FECHA_NACIMIENTO,'DD "de" Month') "DÍA DE CUMPLEAMOS"
     , DIRECCION "DIRECIÓN CLIENTE"
FROM SYN_C2;
```

Comment: Por favor redacta un título introductorio y que tenga referencia con la pregunta, por otro lado ¿qué has intentado de momento?. Recomiendo leas [ask]

Comment: Edita la pregunta, para que el titulo explique el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esta cláusula al final:

`WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FECHA_NACIMIENTO) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),1)))`

En la que se le está indicando que el mes de la fecha de nacimiento sea igual al mes actual mas un mes.

Me tomé la libertad de recrear parte de tu tabla en SQL Fiddle para validar la información *teniendo en cuenta que es el mes 11 (noviembre)* y quedaría algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE SYN_C2
       (NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50) ,
        FECHA_NACIMIENTO DATE ) ;

INSERT INTO SYN_C2 VALUES
        ('JUAN VALDEZ',TO_DATE('17-12-1980','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO SYN_C2 VALUES
        ('PEDRO INFANTE',TO_DATE('02-11-1992','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO SYN_C2 VALUES
        ('TITO NIEVES',TO_DATE('23-12-1978','DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

El query simulado quedaría así:

```
SELECT NOMBRE
       , TO_CHAR(FECHA_NACIMIENTO,'DD "de" Month') "DÍA DE CUMPLEAMOS"
FROM SYN_C2
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FECHA_NACIMIENTO) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),1)));
```

Y la salida quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo [un enlace a la docu](https://ora.u440.com/fecha/add_months.html) de `ADD_MONTHS()` y [a la docu](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) de `EXTRACT()`

Comment: Sin haber probado la solución (porque no tengo acceso a Oracle), pero ¿eso no truncaría para dejar año y mes? Eso haría que solo muestre las personas que nazcan el próximo mes (dato difícil de obtener)

Comment: Tienes razón @LuisCazares , no me tomé el tiempo de recrear un escenario similar. Gracias por tu observación. Edité la respuesta con información basada en la salida obtenida en SQL Fiddle.